# Maximum number of junit tests in test results in Netbeans 7.3.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Hello fellow developers,

i am working myself through the TDD-method of coding and therefore have created a vast (maybe too large?) number of testcases for the various states and branches my application can be in.

One of these testclasses has 34 testcases, however only 26 are shown to have been executed in the test results. The others are also run as i can see them fail in stout, but the results would show 26 testcases run successfully.

When i comment out one the earlier 26 testcases one of the next testcases in line is shown in the testresults.

When i comment out all testcases but one and then uncomment one at a time, all goes well until i hit the (magic?) number 26 and it does not matter which testcases are active at the time.

Has anyone else encountered this or does anyone have a hint as to where to look?
As there are quite a few external libraries involved i am not sure the testcode will do any good here.

EDIT: 
Environment:
Netbean 7.3.1
Java 1.6.0.39
JUnit 4.11
Hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
EasyMock 3.2

Comment: Please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/